# barra de navegacion colapsable de boostrap no muestra menu

Tags: html5, css3, web, bootstrap-3

estoy haciendo una barra de navegacion con bootstrap de tipo collapse para cuando sea vista en mobiles, pero al disminuir el tamaño de la pagina en elnavegador me salen solo las 3 lineas de icono del menu pero no me lo muestra cuando le doy click
este es el codigo que llevo de la pagina

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Portfolio freeCodeCamp tutorials">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
    <!-- bootstrap links -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>ejemplo portfolio</title>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar"><!-- offset ? -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a id="logo" class="navbar-brand" href="#">Malditagaseosa</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="social" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="www.github.com"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="www.instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que está haciendo la llamada a `Bootstrap` después de `Jquery`. y debería ser al contrario ya que `bootstrap` requiere de `Jquery`. El Orden sería.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era eso